# Changing integration limits in a Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I've been reading [these notes about the Fourier transform of Heaviside function](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~bueler/M611heaviside.pdf), but I don't fully understand the derivation right after formula (5) - why does it hold only for $t>0$? The author mentions it is due to step **, but as I understand it

$$ \int_a^b f(x) dx = \left[\begin{matrix}u=-x\\f(x) = f(-u) \\ dx = -du\end{matrix}   \right] =  - \int_{-a}^{-b}f(-u)du = \int_{-b}^{-a}f(-u)du.$$

So the expression in the notes would be

$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{i\omega t}}{\omega} d\omega= -\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-iu t}}{u} du $$

which holds $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, and integration variable $u$ can be renamed back to $\omega$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative sign does not come from step **. It comes from the last step

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin \omega t}{\omega}\, d\omega$$

When you solve this integral using change of variable, it depends on the sign of $t$ to make the upper limit $\infty$ or $-\infty$.